# How to generate .orc file from Oracle tables?

Tags: oracle, hive, bigdata, orc

I have Oracle DB tables and I am seeing .orc files in S3 bucket.
Just want to know how .orc files are generated from Oracle DBs?

Comment: They aren't generated by Oracle. Oracle doesn't create ORC files, though it can read them as external tables (read only) with the right drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I came to know Spark job creates ORC files